# Disable UITableViewcontroller from rotating in Landscape (keep it Portrait orientation)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6

I'm trying to keep ***UITableViewcontroller*** in Portrait orientation. Hence, I don't want to rotate to Landscape mode. I added below method. But it didn't help, notice I'm using iOS 8:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
     if(interfaceOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        return YES;
    }else
    {
        return NO;
    }

}
```

Notice, I'm calling the UITableView through ***UINavigationController***

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                    initWithRootViewController:svc];
    // configure the new view controller explicitly here.

    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion: nil];
```

Comment: You mean you want UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown?

Comment: No .. I just done't want the view to rotate to landscape.

Comment: You can set available rotation modes in info.plist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the enabled orientation interface in the Info.plist or, if you want only the Table in this way, you have to modify manually the `supportInterfaceOrientation` in the navigationController when you are presenting the view. The 'child' will assume the values from the navigationController. Then, when you dismiss the table, you have to reset the `supportInterfaceOrientation` manually.